# How can I detect if a program is running from within valgrind?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, valgrind

Is there a way to identify at run-time of an executable is being run from within valgrind?  I have a set of C++ unit tests, and one of them expects `std::vector::reserve` to throw `std::bad_alloc`.  When I run this under valgrind, it bails out completely, preventing me from testing for both memory leaks (using valgrind) and behavior (expecting the exception to be thrown).

Here's a minimal example that reproduces it:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    size_t uint_max = static_cast<size_t>(-1);
    std::vector<char> v;
    v.reserve(uint_max);
}
```

Running valgrind, I get this output:

```
Warning: silly arg (-1) to __builtin_new()
new/new[] failed and should throw an exception, but Valgrind
   cannot throw exceptions and so is aborting instead.  Sorry.
   at 0x40192BC: VALGRIND_PRINTF_BACKTRACE (valgrind.h:319)
   by 0x401C823: operator new(unsigned) (vg_replace_malloc.c:164)
   by 0x80487BF: std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned) new_allocator.h:92)
   by 0x804874D: main (vg.cxx:6)
```

I'd like to modify my unit test to simply skip the offending code when it's being run from within valgrind.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should look at [this page](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.clientreq) from the Valgrind manual, it contains a `RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND` macro (included from valgrind.h) which does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been using *grind for years but hardly touched the interface. Its easy to make sanity to include that macro in autoconf .. which automatically turns on my debug printfs() and assertions when running under valrgind if valgrind/valgrind.h is present :)

Thanks again! Very helpful

Answer (score 7):

If one does not want to include `valgrind.h` (which requires an autoconf test or similar) or use a wrapper, here's a heuristic for Linux (and other systems using ELF?): test the value of the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable since Valgrind works by preloading libraries. I use the following test in C to check whether `LD_PRELOAD` contains the string `"/valgrind/"` or `"/vgpreload"`:

```
int tests_run_within_valgrind (void)
{
  char *p = getenv ("LD_PRELOAD");
  if (p == NULL)
    return 0;
  return (strstr (p, "/valgrind/") != NULL ||
          strstr (p, "/vgpreload") != NULL);
}
```

Other systems might have a similar solution. I suggest the following command to see whether the environment mentions Valgrind:

```
valgrind env | grep -i valgrind
```

Edit:
In the relatively unlikely event that you are trying to do this either on macOS or on FreeBSD i386 running on an amd64 kernel then the environment variables are different.

- macOS uses DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
- FreeBSD uses LD_32_PRELOAD (ONLY for i386 on amd64, not amd64 on amd64 or i386 on i386).

Plain LD_PRELOAD should work for all Linux and Solaris variants.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the valgrind doucmentation and didn't find an easy answer.  But here are a couple of things you can try:

- Write your own wrapper around the offending new operation and raise the exception before valgrind gets its private new function going.
- Try as poster above suggested except that instead of a command-line option (which requires plumbing) use an environment variable:

  ```
  MYAPP_UNIT_TESTS_DISABLED="NEW_MINUS_ONE,FLY_TO_MOON,DEREF_NULL" valgrind myapp
  ```

Then you can easily write a function

```
bool unit_test_enabled(const char *testname);
```

to protect your unit test based on the value returned by getenv(3).